# Proper data structure for d3 nodes

Tags: json, d3.js

I want to build force-directed graph using d3. Each nodes of the graph is a character from Marvel comics (e.g. Spider-man). If the characters appear in one comic there should be a link between the nodes which represent them.

I have a `characters_by_comics.json` file which contains array of object the following type:

```
  {
    "comic_id": 2,
    "characters": [
      1009220,
      1010776,
      1009378,
      1010363,
      1009215,
      1009471,
      1009718
    ]
  },
```

I also have `characters.json` which contains all info about each character including their `character_id`. In addition, `comics.json` contains the title of every comic and its `comic_id`.

The graph is going to be quiet huge. That will affect user experience in a negative way. So, to prevent this I added some information about each character, such as `race`, `gender`, `alive`, etc. Using this information then I am planning to:

1. Create different filters that can be applied to the graph. For example, if I apply `only female` filter, only the nodes representing female characters should be visible
2. Create different types of links: not only `appear in one comic`, but also `belongs to one team`, for example.

My question is how can I transform the data I have so it is easy to create `nodes` and `links` from it using d3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include a snippet of `characters.json`, but that is your *node* [data](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_nodes).  Sounds like it might already formatted correctly.  It would need to be something like this:

```
var characters = [
  {
    id: 1009220,
    name: 'Ms Marvel'
  }, {
    id: 1010776,
    name: 'Spiderman'
  }
  ....
];
```

Now the real question becomes, how do we get your *link* data from your `characters_by_comics.json`? Assuming a structure like this:

```
var charactersByComic = [{
  "comic_id": 2,
  "characters": [
    1009221,
    1010776,
    ...
  ]
}, {
  "comic_id": 3,
  "characters": [
    1009221,
    1009220,
    1009379,
    ...
  ]
}];
```

You could do it like:

```
var linkData = {}; // object to hold data
charactersByComic.forEach(d0 => { // loop the master data
  d0.characters.forEach(d1 => { // outer loop of characters
    d0.characters.forEach(d2 => { // inner loop of characters
      var key = d1 + "|" + d2; // create unique key to prevent duplicate relationshipts
      if (d1 !== d2 && !linkData[key]) { // if its not the same character, and they don't already have a relationship
        linkData[key] = { // add it
          source: d1,
          target: d2
        };
      }
    });
  });
});
linkData = Object.values(linkData); // take just the array of relationships
```

This would produce our desired *link* [structure](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#links):

```
[
  {"source":1009221,"target":1010776},
  {"source":1009221,"target":1009378},
  ...
]
```

Now we can jam this whole thing into a force directed graph:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    .links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }
    
    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


  <svg width="200" height="200"></svg>

  <script>
    var characters = [{
      id: 1009220,
      name: 'Ms Marvel'
    }, {
      id: 1010776,
      name: 'Spiderman'
    }, {
      id: 1009378
    }, {
      id: 1010363
    }, {
      id: 1009215
    }, {
      id: 1009471
    }, {
      id: 1009718
    }, {
      id: 1009221
    }, {
      id: 1010777
    }, {
      id: 1009379
    }, {
      id: 1010361
    }, {
      id: 1009212
    }, {
      id: 1009474
    }, {
      id: 1009715
    }];
    
    var charactersByComic = [{
      "comic_id": 2,
      "characters": [
        1009221,
        1010776,
        1009378,
        1010363,
        1009215,
        1009471,
        1009718,
        1010777
      ]
    }, {
      "comic_id": 3,
      "characters": [
        1009221,
        1009220,
        1009379,
        1010361,
        1009212,
        1009474,
        1009715,
        1010777
      ]
    }];
    
    var linkData = {};
    charactersByComic.forEach(d0 => {
      d0.characters.forEach(d1 => {
        d0.characters.forEach(d2 => {
          var key = d1 + "|" + d2;
          if (d1 !== d2 && !linkData[key]) {
            linkData[key] = {
              source: d1,
              target: d2
            };
          }
        });
      });
    });
    linkData = Object.values(linkData);  
   
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");


    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        console.log(d)
        return d.id;
      }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

      var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(linkData)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

      var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(characters)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "steelblue");
        
      node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

      simulation
       .nodes(characters)
        .on("tick", ticked);


      simulation.force("link")
        .links(linkData);
      
      console.log(simulation)

      function ticked() {
        link
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });

        node
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          });
      }

  </script>
```